# python3 - import a file in the same directory

Tags: python-3.x

I have a test project that looks like this:

```
_ test_project
├- __init__.py
├- main.py
└- output.py
```

`__init__.py` is empty, and the other two files look like this:

```
# main.py
from . import output
```

and

```
# output.py
print("hello world")
```

I would like to import `output.py` just for the side effect, but I am getting this message instead:

```
(venv) $ python test_project/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_project/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import output
ImportError: cannot import name 'output'
```

What does the import statement in `main.py` have to be to just print "hello world"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relative imports can only be performed in a package. So, run the code as a package.

```
$ cd /pathabovetest_project
$ python -m test_project.main
```

Answer (score 4):

Just do `import output`, that worked for me.